# Bitmap.GetPixel() returns nothing

Tags: c#, bitmap, system.drawing

As the title says, calling Bitmap.GetPixel results in nothing. No value being assigned to the variable, no exceptions being thrown.

Here's my test code:

```
private void frmStatTracker_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
        Color charlie = new Color();
        foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("DM -"))
            {
                sc.CaptureWindowToFile(p.MainWindowHandle, "C:\\test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                Image i = sc.CaptureWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
                Bitmap b = new Bitmap(i);
                pictureBox1.Image = b;

                charlie = b.GetPixel(65, 41);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I breakpoint the code, I get the following:

i has a valid image in it from the screenCapture.

b has a valid image in it.

charlie is left with no value. When I add it to the watch list, it tells me that charlie does not exist in the current context, and the variable does not exist in the Locals window. If I breakpoint either the declaration, or the line where it assigns a value, the breakpoint will be hit and appear to be run.

I'm at my wits end, and have no idea how to even start troubleshooting something like this. Help?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Don't debug release builds unless you have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are debugging a release (or other optimized) build.  That's why `charlie` doesn't exist.  The variable has only been assigned, not otherwise used.  The compiler has optimized it away.

EDIT: You can prevent this by using a Debug build, or, as David Heffernan said, by doing something meaningful with `charlie`.

Comment: Thanks. I built a release version at 2am last night, and forgot to switch it back.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you write some code that actually does something with `charlie`, then the compiler will stop optimizing it away.

For example, if you had a function called `snort(Color color)` then writing:

```
charlie = b.GetPixel(65, 41);
snort(charlie);
```

would (probably) be enough to force the compiler not to optimize `charlie` away.

Of course, you are probably debugging a release build with optimization enabled. You should change your project settings so that optimizations are disabled when building for debug. When you do that you won't need to resort to tricks to defeat the optimizer. Or perhaps you are just debugging the release build by mistake – you get the idea I trust.

Comment: It was in mistake. Thanks for the pointer, and the creative code :-P